# Amazon cloudfront caching images on magmi import

Tags: magento, caching, amazon-web-services, magmi

I am importing a feed of approx 2.000 items into a Magento db using Magmi.

All product images are imported remote and the source is an Amazon CloudFront server (which might be the source of the problem).

Everything appears to be working fine (no errors on import console like *not found* or *denied access*), however some products have misplaced images (images of other products).

I verified the fallowing:

1. permissions for `media/catalog` folder
2. permissions for `media/temp` folder
3. removed `media/catalog/product/cache`
4. disabled all magento caching
5. cleared all browser caching
6. magmi setting for "Image attributes processor" for import mode is "Override existing images"
7. removed all content of `var/cache`

I have searched for a solution to this regarding:

1. delaying each sku import in magmi (did not find a solution to this but might be a solution to bypass a number of subsequent fast requests to Amazon)
2. settings on cloudfront requests on high capacity from a single IP (however settings on this kind of servers can be very broad and difficult to identify from outside)

**Update #1:**

I have tried the same on a fresh Magento installation and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: There should be some setting to put it on development mode to stop the issue.

Comment: @Muk - The Amazon server is not in my administration. The feed is provided by a 3'rd party.